# Protocol for leader election

Tags: protocol-design

A leader should be selected by randomly choosing one of three parties A, B and C. The parties use the following
protocol:

$A → B: N_A$ (where $N_A$ is a nonce)

$B → C:$ $N_{AB}$ $= N_A$ ^ $N_B$ (where $N_B$ is a nonce, and ^ is the ex-or operation}

$C → A:$ $N_{ABC}$ $= N_{AB}$ ^ $N_C$ (where $N_C$ is a nonce)
( Now both A and C know $N_{ABC}$)

$A → B$: $N_{ABC}$
(Now B knows $N_{ABC}$, too)

( Each of the three parties can now compute $p = N_{ABC} mod 3$, where $p = 0$ denotes A, $p = 1$ denotes B, and $p = 2$
denotes C ).

Discuss the security of the protocol and establish if and how is it possible for some of the parties to deterministically choose the leader,
being the others not aware of the fraud.

Then fix the protocol too.

I am training with security exercises, but I don't know how to approach to this. Can you give me some help?

Comment: I'll give you a clue - Whenever you have a protocol where parties do not commit to their votes, but see them in the clear, the last actor has an un-fair advantage over the others. Why?

Comment: Well hence I suppose that, in this case, C can choose a nonce $N_C$ in a way that $N_{ABC}$ will output himself as leader, since he is the first to compute the final nonce. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Now what can we do to prevent this? Hint: read about commitment schemes

Comment: Could this be a fix? Using crypto hashing function, A sends to B and C the hash of his nonce, B and C do the same. Then all of them send to the others own nonce in clear, so now they can check the truth of the previous messages. But in this case do the XOR operations affect in some way my fix? Should I change something more? I mean, can I "ignore" the XOR until all the parties have all nonces in clear, so then they apply the XOR?

Comment: yes but you need the nonces to be big enough, say - 32 bytes.

Comment: Why this, if I can ask?

Comment: well assume the nonces are small, let's say - they are only 4 bytes which is 32 bits. This means that the last participant can find the pre-image of the hash by trying all 2^32 possibilities which is only like 4 billion possibilities.

Comment: Thank you, got it! 
So hashing is sufficient? Do you think are not necessary timestamps/counters?